# Geometry problem with angles

Tags: geometry

[image]

How do I prove that angle B is 90 degrees?

Or, in other words, that the right triangle with AB as its hypotenuse and the right triangle with BC as its hypotenuse are both similar

Comment: This is Thales's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple: $AC^2=4c^2, AB^2=a^2+(c+b)^2, BC^2=a^2+(c-b)^2$

$AB^2+BC^2=2a^2+2b^2+2c^2+2bc-2bc=4c^2=AC^2$

Answer (score 0):

Denote by $O$ the center of the circle. Then, $\angle ABO = \alpha$, $\angle AOB=\pi -2\alpha$, and $\angle BOC = 2\alpha$ as the $\triangle ABC$ is isosceles. $\triangle BOC$ is also isosceles and $\angle OBC = \pi/2 -1/2\angle BOC =  \pi/2 - \alpha$. Thus, $\angle ABC = \alpha/2 + \pi/2 - \alpha/2= \pi/2.$

Answer (score 0):

If $\overline{AC}$ is a diameter, then the measure of $\angle ABC$ is one-half the measure of arc $AC$ is $\frac 12180^\circ = 90^\circ$.